# How do I enable ESLint classPrivateMethods parser plugin?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint

I'm trying to use the `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods` plugin with ESLint, however, any code using the new features causes this error:

> ESLint: Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'classPrivateMethods'

Based on this error message it's not immediately obvious where this plugin should be enabled, and I could not find any instructions on how to add "parser plugins" to my `.eslintrc` (shown below).

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "jquery": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "script",
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "camelcase": 0,
        "curly": 0,
        "wrap-iife": [
            2,
            "any"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": 2,
        "comma-style": [
            2,
            "last"
        ],
        "new-cap": 2,
        "strict": [
            2,
            "function"
        ],
        "no-undef": 2,
        "no-unused-vars": 0,
        "no-console": 0,
        "react/prop-types": 0
    }
}
```

How do I enable this parser plugin?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There was an issue for this in the babel-eslint repo: https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/pull/523

It's recently been resolved and the fix is released in `babel-eslint@11.0.0-beta.0` [source](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/pull/711#issuecomment-456203896)

Once `babel-eslint@11.0.0` is available, you can upgrade and plugins will be loaded from your Babel configuration file.

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"
  ]
};
```

Comment: The `babel-eslint` package version `11.0.0` is still not available, but the latest beta version is `11.0.0-beta.2`

Comment: `babel-eslint` is now `@babel/eslint-parser`. The configuration can be put directly to .eslintrc.js:

`module.exports = { parserOptions: { babelOptions: { plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties"]}}};`

Answer (score 10):

It is October now but `babel-eslint@11.0.0` still not released yet. In the meantime, you can apply the solution below, which currently working for me

1. Install theses packages

   - `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`
   - `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods`
   - `@babel/eslint-parser`
2. Enable `classPrivateProperties` and `classPrivateMethods` in your
   `.eslintrc.json` or your `package.json` (eslintConfig)
   [image]
3. Change the parser in your `.eslintrc.js`
   [image]

**Result:**

***I am now able to use private methods in my code without eslint error***
[image]

***husky pre-commit hook also work***
[image]

Feel free to comment if you get any problem implementing this solution.

Peace!

Comment: Works great except now ESLint won't auto-fix anything.

Comment: definitely doesn't work for me. Where do the classPrivateProperties/Methods plugins come from? are they internal from the Babel ESLint parser?

Comment: Hi @igorsantos07, not sure if I understand you correctly, but you will need to install these two packages first as I mentioned in step #1 @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties; @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods. Then you can enable these plugins within your .eslintrc.json or your package.json in step #2

Comment: Per the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options) `es6` automatically sets the `ecmaVersion` parser option to 6.  This is inconsistent with the `ecmaVersion` in your `eslintrc`.  Do you perhaps want to replace `es6` with `es2020` and drop the explicit `ecmaVersion`?

Comment: Note: With `es2021` the `plugins` line seems not to be needed.

Comment: And here I am, back again, trying to load another Babel plugin and failing miserably. I tried changing my parser to `@babel/eslint-parser`, but it still complains "cannot find module eslint-plugin-classPrivateMethods". I was wondering... why you have two config sets for a single project?

Answer (score 4):

After years...
Based on @Nidust answer, I realized that we need some more steps:

1. Install these packages: *(+ @babel/core)*
   `npm i @babel/core @babel/eslint-parser @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods -D`
2. Edit or create a `.eslintrc.json` file:

   ```json
   {
       ...
       "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
       "parserOptions": {
           ...
           "babelOptions": {
               "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"]
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. You'll also need a `.babelrc` (at least, empty) file:

   ```json
   {}
   ```

be happy! :)

---

This is my full `.eslintrc.json` file with airbnb config:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "babelOptions": {
            "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"]
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "import/extensions": ["error", "always", { "ignorePackages": true} ]
    }
}
```

VS Code:
[image: VS Code with ESLint and private fields]

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to instal babel-eslint@11.0.0-beta-2 and change my eslint config.

Heres my eslint config in package.json:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 12,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "classPrivateMethods",
      "babel"
    ],
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-console": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 1,
      "babel/semi": 1
    }
  }
```

What's important is to set your `"parser":"babel-eslint"` and then set your `"plugins":["classPrivateMethods","babel"]`